# How to use setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener for Android Wear

Tags: android, user-interface, listener, wear-os

I'm trying to detect when my app is run on a round Wear device, but I can't get the OnApplyWindowInsetsListener to work from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525582/is-there-any-way-to-detect-if-the-clock-is-round).

Can I just attach this to any view object in my layout, or my layout itself?  When is it called? I can't get the listener to fire. Any code examples would be much appreciated.

I create and add this ImageView to my main layout in my OnResume method:

```
backgroundImage = new ImageView(this);
    backgroundImage.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
        @Override
        public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View view, WindowInsets windowInsets) {
            if (windowInsets.isRound()){
                Log.d("DEVELOPER", "......screen is round");
            }
            Log.d("DEVELOPER", "......windowinsets called");
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience not all views call this listener.

Check also the doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onApplyWindowInsets(android.view.WindowInsets)

Using a `WatchViewStub` you can easily obtain it:

```
WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
stub.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
            @Override
            public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {

                if(insets.isRound()) {
                    // Yes device is round
                } 
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Here the layout used:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/stub"
        app:rectLayout="@layout/rect_layout"
        app:roundLayout="@layout/round_layout"/>
```